# MetroSet UI error after installing vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, nuget, nuget-package

After installing it when I try to use it gives me an error

> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'MetroSet UI,
>   Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: It is hard to tell exactly what you installed and in what order. Was it Visual Studio 2019? Did you get the nuget package through the nuget manager?

Comment: It seems to me as the compiler error, not the run-time error. Is the reference to MetroSet UI present in your solution? When you expand "Reference" do you see MetroSet? Do you specify "Import" statement in your code?